# Debugging a crashed process using Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using Pycharm 2019.2.5 and Python 3.6 on Ubuntu.
After a process crashed, is it possible to upload a crash dump into Pycharm in order to view the last state before the crash?
Recreating the error is not possible since it happens very rarely and I can't figure it from the error shown in Pycharm's debugger.

Thank you!

Comment: are you want to store error and what is the meaning of last state (according to context or data)

Comment: I would like to see the values of all variables at the moment of the crash. Preferably in all threads.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in the way you want to use it. Your best bet is to either dump all variables at regular intervals/when the crash happens (depending on the crash), use the pycharm debugger + breakpoints or tell us what kind of crash you have.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Since I do not know when exactly did the crash happened it is very challenging to implement. Thanks anyway.

Comment: show me some of your code so we are able to tell you where could be error and you should apply degugger..

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately I cannot do that. My question was a more general one and not exactly code specific. I would like to know how to recover crush dump files like in windbg (windows) using Pycharm and Ubuntu. I am aware of using the regular Pycharm debug options.